# Kafka Stream: can't get data from Kafka persistent keyValue state store

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am using Kafka streams and persistent KeyValue store in my application. There are two KeyValue stores I am using and two processors. I am facing issue with the stateStore which is shared between two processors. NameProcessor put data into nameStore and EventProcessor extracts data from nameStore. From Debugging it looks like, NameProcessor is able to put data successfully but when EventProcessor trying to get data from nameStore, it doesn't get any data. Below is the code snippet for Application class, Topology, NameProcessor and EventProcessor. Also, I am using Spring boot parent version 2.4.3, kafka-streams version 2.2.0 and kafka-clients version 2.2.0

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        Properties configs = getKafkaStreamProperties();

        Topology builder = new Topology();

        new ApplicationTopology(builder);

        KafkaStreams stream = new KafkaStreams(builder, configs);

        stream.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((Thread thread, Throwable throwable) -> {
            // here you should examine the throwable/exception and perform an appropriate action!
            logger.error("Uncaught exception in stream, MessageDetail: "+ ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(throwable) + ", Stack Trace: " + throwable.fillInStackTrace());
            Runtime.getRuntime().halt(1);
        });

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(stream::close));

        stream.start();
    }

    private static Properties getKafkaStreamProperties() {
        Properties configs = new Properties();
        configs.setProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, getApplicationId());
        configs.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, getBootstrapServers());
        configs.setProperty(StreamsConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, getRetries());
        configs.setProperty(StreamsConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, getRetryBackOffMs());
        configs.setProperty(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, getReplicationFactor());
        configs.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, getMaxPollIntervalMs());
        return configs;
    }

    public class ApplicationTopology {

    public ApplicationTopology (Topology builder) {

        StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Sensor>> nameStoreBuilder = Stores.
                keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("nameStore"), Serdes.String(), CustomSerdes.getNameSerde()).withCachingEnabled().withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap<>());

        StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, String>> stateStoreBuilder = Stores.
                keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("stateStore"), Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()).withCachingEnabled().withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap<>());


        builder.addSource(AutoOffsetReset.LATEST, "source", Serdes.String().deserializer(), CustomSerdes.getIncomingEventSerde().deserializer(), getInboundTopic())
                .addProcessor(TRANSFORMER, () -> new EventProcessor(), "source")
                .addStateStore(nameStoreBuilder, TRANSFORMER)
                .addSink("sink", getOutboundTopic(), Serdes.String().serializer(), CustomSerdes.getIncomingEventSerde().serializer(), TRANSFORMER);


        //reset to earliest for model config topic as some models could be already on the topic
        builder.addSource(AutoOffsetReset.EARLIEST, "nameStoreSource", Serdes.String().deserializer(), CustomSerdes.getSensorSerde().deserializer(), getInboundSensorUpdateTopic())
                .addProcessor("process", () -> new NameProcessor(), "nameStoreSource")
                .addStateStore(nameStoreBuilder,  TRANSFORMER, "process");

    }

    public ApplicationTopology() {}
    } }



    public class NameProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<String, Sensor> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NameProcessor.class);

    ProcessorContext context;

    private KeyValueStore<String, Name> nameStore;

    private static List<String> externalDeviceIdList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext) {
        this.context = processorContext;
        this.nameStore = (KeyValueStore<String, Name>) context.getStateStore("nameStore");
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String externalDeviceId, Name name) {

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(externalDeviceId)) {
            String[] externalDeviceIds = SensorUtils.getExternalDeviceIdsWithoutSuffix(externalDeviceId);

            if (Objects.isNull(name)) {
                Arrays.stream(externalDeviceIds).forEach(id -> {
                    sensorStore.delete(id);
                });
            } else {
                addOrUpdateNameInStore(sensor, externalDeviceIds);
            }
        }

    }

    private void addOrUpdateNameInStore(Sensor sensor, String[] externalDeviceIds) {

        Arrays.stream(externalDeviceIds).forEach(id -> {
            sensorStore.put(id, sensor);

        });

        // context.commit();
    }

}

    public class EventProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<String, IncomingEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventProcessor.class);

    ProcessorContext context;

    private KeyValueStore<String, Name> nameStore;

    private KeyValueStore<String, String> stateStore;


    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext) {
        this.context = processorContext;

        this.nameStore = (KeyValueStore<String, Name>) context.getStateStore("nameStore");
        this.stateStore = (KeyValueStore<String, String>) context.getStateStore("stateStore");
        
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, IncomingEvent value) {

        String correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        try {

            String externalDeviceId = value.getExternalDeviceId();

           Name nameFromStore = nameStore.get(externalDeviceId);

}
}
}




In nameFromStore variable, I don't get even value even after storing it in NameProcessor.
```

Comment: I ended up using a globalStateStore to fulfil my requirement. It worked as expected.